# Change boxplot limits in R

Tags: r, boxplot, quantile, percentile

I'm trying to change the upper and lower limit of a boxplot.

I need to to change from 5% to 10% (lower) and from 95% to 90% (upper).

Moreover, I have to use the standard boxplot function (no ggplot unfortunately).

I tried to calculate the quantiles (`quantile` function) but I don't know how the boxplot function can understand the new values.

Some ideas?

Comment: Give us some code to play with!

Comment: why can't you  use `ggplot`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A boxplot has the following structure:

[image: Boxplot explanation]

As I understand your question, you need the upper hinge to reflect the occurrences up to the 90% percentile, and the lower inge to reflect the occurrences above 10% percentile.

As far as I know, you can't change the size of the box (which will always go from the 25% percentile to the 75% percentile (1st and 3rd quartile). What you can manipulate is the length of the whiskers, and for that, you can use the `range` argument of the `boxplot()` function (see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/boxplot.html) for the documentation). But you can't set the length of the whisker in terms of the quantiles of the values; you can only set the max length of the whisker in terms of the IQR (Interquartile range: `IQR = abs(quantile(x, 0.75) - quantile(x, 0.25))`). By default, the max length of the whisker will be 1.5 times the IQR  but you can change that:

```
boxplot(x, range=0.5) # This will make the max length of the whisker
                      # to be 0.5 * IQR
```

I don't know if there's a way to make the range of the whisker to be explicitely a quantile (at least with the standard `boxplot()` function)